# click marker google map show a div outside the map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

i need show a div when clicking the google marker, this is the code html:

```
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<div id="info-container">
    <h1>Hola</h1>
</div>
```

and the map js click code:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
  return function() {
       $('#info-container').css('display', 'block');
    })(marker, i));
}
```

but the marker click not add the style

Comment: why not doing `google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){$('#info-container').css('display', 'block');})` ?

Comment: i don't know dude, on the console no have errors

Comment: 1. you have a typo in your HTML (`id="info-container>` is missing a close ", should be id="info-container">` 2. What do you expect it to do?  3. Why are you using function closure if all the markers are going to change the same element?

Comment: I suggest you improve your question and provide a more complete, reproducible example. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: ok i'll improve a fiddle @FernandoCorreia. Sorry my code at sublime have the quotes, the markers open the same div why the info of that container change via ajax

Answer (score 2):

If I change your HTML to fix the typo and so the code makes a visible change to the page, your code works for me:

```
function initialize() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(40, -85),
        zoom: 4
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: map.getCenter(),
        map: map
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function (marker, i) {
        if ($('#info-container').css('display') == 'block') {
            $('#info-container').css('display', 'none');
        } else {
            $('#info-container').css('display', 'block');
        }
    });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Vr24/1/)

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/QRFeX435bm